Is there a way to disable "time limit" for compile time evaluation in Rust?
I have been trying to write a const fn that computes the Sieve of Erastothenes at compile time. It works perfectly until the max size of the Sieve gets to 1e6.
In that case, I get the default message for "long-running-const-eval" (https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/deny-by-default.html#long-running-const-eval).
I have added #[allow(long-running-const-eval)] and it still gives me an error.
What can I do in this situation? Filling the seive should take only a few seconds but the compiler gives up too soon.

Shouldn't it be #[allow(long_running_const_eval)]? Note you'll get a warning even with allow.

It would probably be better to do this in a build script so that you can run it with optimizations. The user of your library can turn on opts by changing [profile.dev/release.package.foo] https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overrides
